# getting twitter followers of specific user

Tags: php, twitter

my site needs to keep track of followers of certain users 
if i want to get the names of all the followers of specific user  lets say this user have 1000 follower
i will be able to get the follower ids by https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json 
1000 id

then to get the username of each id i will have to run  https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json
for each id of those 1000 id but the rate limit of 350 makes this impossible

any solution , what i am doing wronge ?

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the solutino actually in users/lookup as parameter of  user_id i can send multiple ids saperated by commas 
so in single API call i can send upto 100 ids which will mean in one hour i can get the lookup of 35000 users which is more than enough for most of the cases